# timezone issue with mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I insert some data in MySql database along with datetime. When I echo date, it show me correct time but when I insert it into database then it insert 2 hour ahead time.I'm using below for date and time,

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Do I have to change any settings in my cpanel?

Comment: What timezone are you in? MySQL might be normalizing the time to UTC, or otherwise normalizing the timezone

Comment: @JamesPalawaga I'm in dubai/asia but I have users from different countries.I can't set any specific time zone

Comment: You'll want to store all of your timezones in UTC in the database, and then convert those values to the correct timezone of your users on output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); in your config file. Probably your timezone is wrong. Change 'America/Los_Angeles' by the correct for your region.
By config file I mean any file where you concentrate your configuration and you include before of any other code.

Comment: In this case it will enter Lonsangles time but I have users from different countries

Comment: In this  case you can set to UTC like this `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');` and inform to user that it is UTC time date.

Comment: By inform to user I mean do something like that: `date('Y-m-d H:i:s').' UTC';` and not write data explicity.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that a MySQL installation can choose its own non-UTC timezone*, so try to avoid mixing PHP time() and times from MySQL. If you are careful to always store date/time as PHP timestamps (integers), you can format by local timezone and local formatting preference for each user.

- my California-based host uses UTC for PHP and PST for MySQL timestamps.